# CD ROM Drive not detected in Kubuntu 11.10

Tags: kubuntu, cd-drive

I am running kubuntu 11.10 on my Pentium M Laptop (Acer Travelmate 292LCi) on an old 20GB HDD. (It's rather less HDD for Kubuntu 11.10, isn't it?)

Now, I know from older Linux distributions (like Suse or PCLos which I used some years ago) that the CD ROM Drive is mounted automatically and can also be seen in the Konquerer (or like in Kubuntu's case Dolphin).

Now, I partitioned the HDD and when I start Dolphin it says sda1 and sda2, but not the CD ROM Drive.

**Question: Do I have to mount the CD ROM Drive first?**
(Because when I insert a CD in the drive the CD ROM Drive appears and I can read the content of the CD.)
**But I want the CD ROM Drive to be visible all the time**, not only when I insert a CD. (Like it was the case with the Linux distributions I used some years ago and like it is the case in Windows)

**Does anyone have a console-code or so for me concerning this matter?**

Thank you,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

First you must see which mountpoint has your cdrom. Just insert a cd, have it mount it, and do a `sudo fdisk -l`.

After that eject the cd to unmount the cdrom drive.

Try and mount the cdrom manually:

```
mount /dev/CDROM_DRIVE /media/cdrom
```

Either `/media/cdrom` or whatever directory you want cdrom mounted.

If it works, put that information on `/etc/fstab` to make it permanent

```
/dev/sdc0        /media/cdrom   iso9660 ro,user,noauto  0       0
```